# NSIS selected options odd behaviour

Tags: nsis

I am not an NSIS pro but I get by! I am setting up a new installer for a new piece of software we are building, I have configured the installer up with 2 potential paths, install or upgrade.

The idea is that when a user selects any of the upgrade options all options that may be selected for install are deselected and vice versa.

What is happening for me at the moment is when a user for example, selects one option under the install path, all options for that path are being selected and are not deselectable unless you select an option under the upgrade path, after which interestingly, selection of options then appears to behave as wanted?

Here is my code, what obvious thing am I missing here??

```
;--------------------------------
;Includes
;--------------------------------

  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  !include "nsDialogs.nsh"
  !include "LogicLib.nsh"
  !include "Sections.nsh"
  !include "oledb.nsh"
  !include "WinMessages.nsh"
  !include "ReplaceInFile.nsh"



;--------------------------------
;General
;--------------------------------

    ;Name and file
    Name "App"
    OutFile "AppName ${Version}.exe"

    ;Default installation folder
    InstallDir "C:\appFolder"

    ;Request application privileges for Windows Vista +
    RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings
;--------------------------------

    !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
    Var Dialog
    Var SQLServer
    Var SQLUsername
    Var SQLPassword
    Var SDatabase
    Var CoreDatabase
    Var UIDatabase

    ShowInstDetails "show"

;--------------------------------
;Pages
;--------------------------------

    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "LIC.rtf"
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
    Page Custom SQLConnectionDetails SQLConnectionDetailsPageLeave
    Page Custom DatabaseDetails DatabaseDetailsLeave
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;onInit
;--------------------------------

Function .onInit
    InitPluginsDir
    StrCpy $1 "SecMain"

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Page functions
;--------------------------------   

Function SQLConnectionDetails
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(SQLServerDetailsTitle) $(SQLServerDetailsSubTitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ;x, y, width, height and text
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 10u "Enter the name of the SQL server that AppName is to be installed on"
    pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 10u 150u 12u ""
    pop $SQLServer

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 25u 100% 10u "Enter the database name"
    pop $2
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 35u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SDatabase

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 50u 100% 10u "Enter SQL username"
    pop $3
    ${NSD_CreateText}} 0 60u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SQLUsername

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 75u 100% 10u "Enter SQL password"
    pop $4
    ${NSD_CreatePassword} 0  85u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SQLPassword

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function SQLConnectionDetailsPageLeave
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLServer $SQLServer
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLUsername $SQLUsername
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLPassword $SQLPassword
    ${NSD_GetText} $SDatabase $SDatabase
    messagebox MB_OK "We will now attempt to connect to the database server."
    MSSQL_OLEDB::SQL_Logon "$SQLServer" "$SQLUsername" "$SQLPassword"
    pop $0

    ${If} $0 = 0
        ;messagebox MB_OK "Connection sucessful"
    ${Else}
        messagebox MB_OK "I encountered an issue whilst trying to connect to the database. Please check your details and try again."
        abort
    ${EndIf}

    MSSQL_OLEDB::SQL_Logout
FunctionEnd

Function DatabaseDetails
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(DatabaseNamesTitle) $(DatabaseNamesSubTitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ;x, y, width, height and text
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 10u "Enter the name to be given to the Core database"
    pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 10u 150u 12u ""
    pop $CoreDatabase

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 25u 100% 10u "Enter the name to be given to the UI database"
    pop $2
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 35u 100u 12u ""
    pop $UIDatabase

    nsDialogs::Show
 FunctionEnd

 Function DatabaseDetailsLeave
 ${NSD_GetText} $CoreDatabase $CoreDatabase
 ${NSD_GetText} $UIDatabase $UIDatabase
 FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Languages
;--------------------------------

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections
;--------------------------------
InstType "New Install"
InstType "New Install - Full"
InstType "Upgrade"

;------------
;New Install
;------------

SectionGroup /e "!Install" SecGroupNewInstall
    Section "Main App" SecMain

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App1" SecApp1

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App2" SecApp2

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App3" SecApp3

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App4" SecApp4

    SectionEnd

    SectionGroup /e "Optional" SubSecGroupNewInstall
        Section /o "App5" SecApp5

        SectionEnd

        Section /o "App6" SecApp6

        SectionEnd  

        Section /o "App7" SecApp7

        SectionEnd
    SectionGroupEnd 
SectionGroupEnd

SectionGroup /e "!Upgrade" SecGroupUpgrade
    Section /o "Upgrade Main App" SecMainUpgrade        
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

;--------------------------------
;onSelChange
;--------------------------------

Function .onSelChange

    !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $1
        !insertmacro RadioButton ${SecMain}
        !insertmacro RadioButton ${SecMainUpgrade}
    !insertmacro EndRadioButtons

    !insertmacro SectionFlagIsSet ${SecMain} ${SF_SELECTED} InstisSel InstnotSel
        InstnotSel:
            !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecGroupNewInstall}
        InstisSel:

    !insertmacro SectionFlagIsSet ${SecMainUpgrade} ${SF_SELECTED} UpgisSel UpgnotSel
        UpgnotSel:
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecGroupUpgrade}
        UpgisSel:

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

I have answered my own question!! 
The issue was down to both timing, and an issue with my onInit function. I have moved my onInit function below my section groups and corrected the StrCpy to now include the correct section reference, see corrected code below:

```
;--------------------------------
;Includes
;--------------------------------

  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  !include "nsDialogs.nsh"
  !include "LogicLib.nsh"
  !include "Sections.nsh"
  !include "oledb.nsh"
  !include "WinMessages.nsh"
  !include "ReplaceInFile.nsh"



;--------------------------------
;General
;--------------------------------

    ;Name and file
    Name "App"
    OutFile "AppName ${Version}.exe"

    ;Default installation folder
    InstallDir "C:\appFolder"

    ;Request application privileges for Windows Vista +
    RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------
;Interface Settings
;--------------------------------

    !define MUI_ABORTWARNING
    Var Dialog
    Var SQLServer
    Var SQLUsername
    Var SQLPassword
    Var SDatabase
    Var CoreDatabase
    Var UIDatabase

    ShowInstDetails "show"

;--------------------------------
;Pages
;--------------------------------

    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "LIC.rtf"
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
    Page Custom SQLConnectionDetails SQLConnectionDetailsPageLeave
    Page Custom DatabaseDetails DatabaseDetailsLeave
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
    !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

;--------------------------------
;Page functions
;--------------------------------   

Function SQLConnectionDetails
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(SQLServerDetailsTitle) $(SQLServerDetailsSubTitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ;x, y, width, height and text
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 10u "Enter the name of the SQL server that AppName is to be installed on"
    pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 10u 150u 12u ""
    pop $SQLServer

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 25u 100% 10u "Enter the database name"
    pop $2
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 35u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SDatabase

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 50u 100% 10u "Enter SQL username"
    pop $3
    ${NSD_CreateText}} 0 60u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SQLUsername

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 75u 100% 10u "Enter SQL password"
    pop $4
    ${NSD_CreatePassword} 0  85u 100u 12u ""
    pop $SQLPassword

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function SQLConnectionDetailsPageLeave
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLServer $SQLServer
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLUsername $SQLUsername
    ${NSD_GetText} $SQLPassword $SQLPassword
    ${NSD_GetText} $SDatabase $SDatabase
    messagebox MB_OK "We will now attempt to connect to the database server."
    MSSQL_OLEDB::SQL_Logon "$SQLServer" "$SQLUsername" "$SQLPassword"
    pop $0

    ${If} $0 = 0
        ;messagebox MB_OK "Connection sucessful"
    ${Else}
        messagebox MB_OK "I encountered an issue whilst trying to connect to the database. Please check your details and try again."
        abort
    ${EndIf}

    MSSQL_OLEDB::SQL_Logout
FunctionEnd

Function DatabaseDetails
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT $(DatabaseNamesTitle) $(DatabaseNamesSubTitle)
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    pop $Dialog
    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ;x, y, width, height and text
    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 10u "Enter the name to be given to the Core database"
    pop $1
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 10u 150u 12u ""
    pop $CoreDatabase

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 25u 100% 10u "Enter the name to be given to the UI database"
    pop $2
    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 35u 100u 12u ""
    pop $UIDatabase

    nsDialogs::Show
 FunctionEnd

 Function DatabaseDetailsLeave
 ${NSD_GetText} $CoreDatabase $CoreDatabase
 ${NSD_GetText} $UIDatabase $UIDatabase
 FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;Languages
;--------------------------------

  !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections
;--------------------------------
InstType "New Install"
InstType "New Install - Full"
InstType "Upgrade"

;------------
;New Install
;------------

SectionGroup /e "!Install" SecGroupNewInstall
    Section "Main App" SecMain

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App1" SecApp1

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App2" SecApp2

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App3" SecApp3

    SectionEnd

    Section /o "App4" SecApp4

    SectionEnd

    SectionGroup /e "Optional" SubSecGroupNewInstall
        Section /o "App5" SecApp5

        SectionEnd

        Section /o "App6" SecApp6

        SectionEnd  

        Section /o "App7" SecApp7

        SectionEnd
    SectionGroupEnd 
SectionGroupEnd

SectionGroup /e "!Upgrade" SecGroupUpgrade
    Section /o "Upgrade Main App" SecMainUpgrade        
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

;--------------------------------
;onInit
;--------------------------------

Function .onInit
    InitPluginsDir
    StrCpy $1 ${SecMain}

FunctionEnd

;--------------------------------
;onSelChange
;--------------------------------

Function .onSelChange

    !insertmacro StartRadioButtons $1
        !insertmacro RadioButton ${SecMain}
        !insertmacro RadioButton ${SecMainUpgrade}
    !insertmacro EndRadioButtons

    !insertmacro SectionFlagIsSet ${SecMain} ${SF_SELECTED} InstisSel InstnotSel
        InstnotSel:
            !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecGroupNewInstall}
        InstisSel:

    !insertmacro SectionFlagIsSet ${SecMainUpgrade} ${SF_SELECTED} UpgisSel UpgnotSel
        UpgnotSel:
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecGroupUpgrade}
        UpgisSel:

FunctionEnd
```